# Terraform: Allow all internal traffic inside aws security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, cidr

I am trying to allow all tcp traffic between instances, otherwise deny all ingress and egress traffic.

Problem with "cidr_blocks", in aws console i can select security group but in terraform how can achieve something like that.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "default" {

  name = "terraform_example" 

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks =  ????
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your ingress rule specification set [self = true](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#self) to allow traffic inside your Security Group. To allow traffic from a different Security Group, use the [security_groups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#security_groups) parameter. In both cases you can leave out the cidr_blocks parameter.

Answer (score 4):

- If your requirement is to allow all the traffic from internet you can use

```
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
```

---

- If you want to allow traffic from a specify VPC which is already created in AWS you can give variable of that cidr

```
    cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.main.cidr_block]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.main.ipv6_cidr_block]
```

---

- If your requirement is to allow from a specific Security group we can also do that

```
    security_groups = [ "aws_security_group.main_sg1.name", "aws_security_group.main_sg2.name" ]
```

---